# Next/Previous Slide on Button click with jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I'm no genius with jQuery, and wondering if someone can just give me a pointer as to what is wrong with this code I am using. The slider works but I need to go to the next and previous slides by pressing the left and right keys.

It could very well be an obvious mistake I have overlooked. At the moment, nothing happens when I press a key.

**jQuery**

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx:'scrollHorz',
                easing:'easeInOutCirc',
                speed:700,
                timeout:5000,
                pager:'.slideshow_wrapper .slideshow-paging'
            });
            $('.slideshow_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
                $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $('.slideshow').cycle('resume');
            }).keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.keycode == 37)
                $('.slideshow').cycle('prev');
            if(e.keycode == 39)
                $('.slideshow').cycle('next');
            })
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="gallery" class="slideshow_wrapper">
<div class="slideshow-paging"></div>
<div class="slideshow">
    <article class="slideshow_item">
        <div class='image'>
            <a href='#'>
                <img src='[URL HERE]' />
            </a>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: does it even cycle without keypress events?

Comment: Sorry. I should have included that. Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attached the keyup event handler to the slideshow wrapper, so that would need to have focus for the handler to be fired. Attach it to document instead.  Also, use `which` instead of keycode...

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx:'scrollHorz',
        easing:'easeInOutCirc',
        speed:700,
        timeout:5000,
        pager:'.slideshow_wrapper .slideshow-paging'
    });
    $('.slideshow_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.slideshow').cycle('resume');
    })
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 37)
            $('.slideshow').cycle('prev');
        if(e.which == 39)
            $('.slideshow').cycle('next');
    });
});
```

Also, depending on what version of jQuery you are using, you will probably be better off using `on` to assign event handlers...

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx:'scrollHorz',
        easing:'easeInOutCirc',
        speed:700,
        timeout:5000,
        pager:'.slideshow_wrapper .slideshow-paging'
    });
    $('.slideshow_wrapper').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    }).on("mouseleave", function(){
        $('.slideshow').cycle('resume');
    })
    $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 37)
            $('.slideshow').cycle('prev');
        if(e.which == 39)
            $('.slideshow').cycle('next');
    });
});
```